# Next.js 13 project serves only cached page on reload

Tags: next.js

I am trying to build a learning project that sends a request to an **API** on every **reload**. I've set `{cache:"no-store"}` and `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";` but to no avail. When I refresh the page, it shows the same result although it should be hitting a totally different endpoint. I'm using Next version 13.4.1

```
async function getTodo() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
    {
      cache: "no-store",
    }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default async function Todo() {
  const todo = await getTodo();
  return <h2>{todo.title}</h2>;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're on < 13.3, there was an issue you can read [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42290)

Comment: I'm in version 13.4.1

Comment: `{cache:"no-store"}` can be set on the server side not client, when sending a request from a react functional component you will need to use [useEffect hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect),

Comment: @SumanKundu all components in Next 13 are server components by default. If I re-write this for the client side then how will I be able to hide api keys and other confidential info?

Comment: I identified the solution. Actually the issue was being caused by Turbo which I was using in the dev environment.